# How to solve the non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

The ODE is
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(y(x)y'(x)\right)=-2xy'(x)$$

Comment: Done ! Is there any question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is analytical solution for this. The following is a series solution. This is not hard to do since zero is an ordinary point. This assumes expansion around $x=0$

\begin{gather*}
\boxed{{y^{\prime}}^{2}+y y^{\prime \prime}+2 y^{\prime} x=0}
\end{gather*}
With the expansion point at $x = 0$. Let

\begin{align*} 
y'' &= f\left(  x,y,y^{\prime}\right)\\\\
    &=-\frac{\left(y^{\prime}+2 x \right) y^{\prime}}{y}
\end{align*}

Assuming expansion is at $x_{0}=0$ . Let initial conditions be $y\left(  x_{0}\right)  =y_{0}$ and
$y^{\prime}\left(  x_{0}\right)  =y_{0}^{\prime}$. Using Taylor series gives

\begin{align*}
y\left(  x\right)   &  =y\left(  x_{0}\right)  +\left(  x-x_{0}\right)
y^{\prime}\left(  x_{0}\right)  +\frac{\left(  x-x_{0}\right)  ^{2}}
{2}y^{\prime\prime}\left(  x_{0}\right)  +\frac{\left(  x-x_{0}\right)  ^{3}
}{3!}y^{\prime\prime\prime}\left(  x_{0}\right)  +\cdots\\
&  =y_{0}+xy_{0}^{\prime}+\frac{x^{2}}{2}\left.  f\right\vert _{x_{0}
,y_{0},y_{0}^{\prime}}+\frac{x^{3}}{3!}\left.  f^{\prime}\right\vert
_{x_{0},y_{0},y_{0}^{\prime}}+\cdots\\
&  =y_{0}+xy_{0}^{\prime}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{\left(
n+2\right)  !}\left.  \frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}\right\vert _{x_{0},y_{0}
,y_{0}^{\prime}}
\end{align*}

But
\begin{align}
\frac{df}{dx}  &  =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial
f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{\prime}}
\frac{dy^{\prime}}{dx}\tag{1}\\\\
&  =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y^{\prime
}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{\prime}}y^{\prime\prime}\\\\
&  =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y^{\prime
}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{\prime}}f\\\\
\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}  &  =\frac{d}{dx}\left(  \frac{df}{dx}\right)
\nonumber\\\\
&  =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(  \frac{df}{dx}\right)  +\frac{\partial
}{\partial y}\left(  \frac{df}{dx}\right)  y^{\prime}+\frac{\partial}{\partial
y^{\prime}}\left(  \frac{df}{dx}\right)  f\tag{2}\\\\
\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^{3}}  &  =\frac{d}{dx}\left(  \frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}\right)
\nonumber\\\\
&  =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(  \frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}\right)  +\left(
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}\right)  y^{\prime}
+\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\prime}}\left(  \frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}\right)
f\tag{3}\\\\
&  \vdots\nonumber
\end{align}

And so on. Hence if we name $F_{0}=f\left(  x,y,y^{\prime}\right)  $ then the
above can be written as
\begin{align}
F_{0}  &  =f\left(  x,y,y^{\prime}\right) \tag{4}\\\\
F_{1}  &  =\frac{df}{dx}\nonumber\\\\
&  =\frac{dF_{0}}{dx}\nonumber\\\\
&  =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y^{\prime
}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{\prime}}y^{\prime\prime}\nonumber\\\\
&  =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y^{\prime
}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{\prime}}f\tag{5}\\\\
&  =\frac{\partial F_{0}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F_{0}}{\partial
y}y^{\prime}+\frac{\partial F_{0}}{\partial y^{\prime}}F_{0}\nonumber\\\\
F_{2}  &  =\frac{d}{dx}\left(  \frac{d}{dx}f\right) \nonumber\\\\
&  =\frac{d}{dx}\left(  F_{1}\right) \nonumber\\\\
&  =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F_{1}+\left(  \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial
y}\right)  y^{\prime}+\left(  \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial y^{\prime}
}\right)  y^{\prime\prime}\nonumber\\\\
&  =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F_{1}+\left(  \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial
y}\right)  y^{\prime}+\left(  \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial y^{\prime}
}\right)  F_{0}\nonumber\\\\
&  \vdots\nonumber\\\\
F_{n}  &  =\frac{d}{dx}\left(  F_{n-1}\right) \nonumber\\\\
&  =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F_{n-1}+\left(  \frac{\partial F_{n-1}
}{\partial y}\right)  y^{\prime}+\left(  \frac{\partial F_{n-1}}{\partial
y^{\prime}}\right)  y^{\prime\prime}\nonumber\\\\
&  =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F_{n-1}+\left(  \frac{\partial F_{n-1}
}{\partial y}\right)  y^{\prime}+\left(  \frac{\partial F_{n-1}}{\partial
y^{\prime}}\right)  F_{0} \tag{6}
\end{align}

Therefore 6) can be used from now on along with
\begin{align*}
y\left(  x\right)  &=y_{0}+xy_{0}^{\prime}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}
}{\left(  n+2\right)  !}\left.  F_{n}\right\vert _{x_{0},y_{0},y_{0}^{\prime}}
\tag{7}
\end{align*}
To find $y\left(  x\right)  $ series solution around $x=0$.
Hence
\begin{align*}
 F_0 &= -\frac{\left(y^{\prime}+2 x \right) y^{\prime}}{y}\\\\
F_1 &= \frac{d F_0}{dx} \\\\ 
 &= \frac{\partial F_{0}}{\partial x}+  \frac{\partial F_{0}}{\partial y} y^{\prime}+ \frac{\partial F_{0}}{\partial y^{\prime}} F_0 \\\\ 
 &= \frac{y^{\prime} \left(3 {y^{\prime}}^{2}+8 y^{\prime} x +4 x^{2}-2 y\right)}{y^{2}}\\\\ 
F_2 &= \frac{d F_1}{dx} \\\\ 
 &= \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial x}+  \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial y} y^{\prime}+ \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial y^{\prime}} F_1 \\\\ 
 &= -\frac{y^{\prime} \left(15 {y^{\prime}}^{3}+50 {y^{\prime}}^{2} x +44 x^{2} y^{\prime}+8 x^{3}-12 y^{\prime} y-12 y x \right)}{y^{3}}\\\\ 
F_3 &= \frac{d F_2}{dx} \\\\ 
 &= \frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x}+  \frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial y} y^{\prime}+ \frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial y^{\prime}} F_2 \\\\ 
 &= \frac{y^{\prime} \left(105 {y^{\prime}}^{4}+420 {y^{\prime}}^{3} x +520 {y^{\prime}}^{2} x^{2}+208 x^{3} y^{\prime}+16 x^{4}-98 {y^{\prime}}^{2} y-172 y^{\prime} y x -48 x^{2} y+12 y^{2}\right)}{y^{4}}
\end{align*}
And so on.
Evaluating all the above at initial conditions $x = 0$ and $y \left(0\right) = y \left(0\right)$ and $y^{\prime}\left(0\right) = y^{\prime}\left(0\right)$ gives
\begin{align*}
 F_0 &= -\frac{{y^{\prime}\left(0\right)}^{2}}{y \left(0\right)}\\\\ 
F_1 &= \frac{3 {y^{\prime}\left(0\right)}^{3}-2 y^{\prime}\left(0\right) y \left(0\right)}{y \left(0\right)^{2}}\\\\ 
F_2 &= \frac{-15 {y^{\prime}\left(0\right)}^{4}+12 {y^{\prime}\left(0\right)}^{2} y \left(0\right)}{y \left(0\right)^{3}}\\\\ 
F_3 &= \frac{105 {y^{\prime}\left(0\right)}^{5}-98 {y^{\prime}\left(0\right)}^{3} y \left(0\right)+12 y^{\prime}\left(0\right) y \left(0\right)^{2}}{y \left(0\right)^{4}}
\end{align*}
Substituting all the above in (7) and simplifying gives the solution as
\begin{align*}
y &= y \left(0\right)
       +x y^{\prime}\left(0\right)+
       \frac{-\frac{{y^{\prime}\left(0\right)}^{2} x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x^{3} y^{\prime}\left(0\right)}{3}}{y \left(0\right)}
       +\frac{\frac{x^{3} {y^{\prime}\left(0\right)}^{3}}{2}+\frac{x^{4} {y^{\prime}\left(0\right)}^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{5} y^{\prime}\left(0\right)}{10}}{y \left(0\right)^{2}}+\dots
\end{align*}